# Fluent NHIbernate ignoring column name on overrided Id property

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have an abstract base class which inherits Sharp Arch's Entity class:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// defines an entity that will ne indexed by a search crawler and offered up as full-text searchable
  /// </summary>
  public abstract class IndexedEntity : Entity
  {
    [DocumentId]
    public override int Id
    {
      get { return base.Id; }
      protected set { base.Id = value; }
    }
  }
```

This is to a legacy db and actually the Id column is called "HelpPageID", so I have some mapping override as:

```
mapping.Id(x => x.Id, "HelpPageID");
```

The generated sql for querying `HelpPage` works fine when I simply inherit `Entity`. But inheriting `IndexedEntity`, when translated to sql, the column name override is ignored and instead `Id` is used for the column, thus failing.

**Edit**
Seems a general issue with an override as placing the override directly in the class has the same net effect

Comment: which inheritance strategy are you using ? TPH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mapping overrides are only executed for the exact type not types which subclass the type in the mappingoverride. you have to specify an override for the subclass.

Comment: you mean the superclass? in which case FNH will ignore it in a TPH scenario due to it being abstract as far as I understand and have experienced